# Linear regression for classification

Tags: regression, logistic, classification, linear-model

Suppose, I have a classification problem with 2 classes (0 and 1) and evaluation criteria is AUC. I used the following method: fit a linear regression and then pass its predictions through the logistic function. 
As far as I understand, it is not equivalent to logistic regression, because estimates of coefficients will be different. And strangely, it works better than logistic regression for my problem. 
Does this linear regression method have any theoretical justifications?
Have you seen it before? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: It seems you've hacked together a kind of shrinkage estimator that pulls predicted probabilities towards 0.5.  However it does so regardless of the data so isn't interpretable as a prior.  This suggests you might do even better with a properly regularised logistic regression model.

Comment: I've tried regularized logistic regression with penalty estimated from CV, but it is always worse than this linear regression. quite bizarre it is

Comment: It might be interesting to compare the ROC curves rather than just compute their areas to see what specifically this model is getting right that other methods are getting wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is not outrageous.

The logistic regression aims to minimize log loss, $L(y,\hat y) = -\sum\bigg[y_i\log(\hat y_i) + (1 - y_i)\log(1 -\hat y_i)
\bigg]$.

Whatever your OLS-based model does, the competing logistic regression is not trying to optimize your metric of interest, so I find it completely believable that an alternative estimation method for the coefficients gives superior performance in terms of AUC.